# Duplicate Hierarchical Data to the same table - Oracle

Tags: oracle, duplicates, hierarchical

How to duplicate hierarchical data to insert them at the same table, generating new Ids but keeping parent-child relationship

Answer (score 0):

Re-insert the data but add the same large number to every ID.

---

**Update:**

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to copy data like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID    MANAGER_ID
1              <null>
2              1
3              1
4              3
```

In this case, just adding 4 to every parent and child ID will create new rows but have the same relationships:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID    MANAGER_ID
5              <null>
6              5
7              5
8              8
```

Comment: I want to generate new sequences but these generated sequences must to keep the relationship like originals rows

Comment: It's exactly what I want to do, Do you have an idea to do it, please??

Comment: Something like `insert into employee select employee_id+4, manager_id+4, [other columns here] from employee;`

Comment: But what will happen if after add this constant number result an existent id?

Comment: Use `select max(employee_id) from employee;` for the constant.

Comment: I followed your recommendation but I notice that using max as constant, table's sequence grows so much.

Comment: I'm not sure what your IDs look like, but maybe `select max(employee_id) - min(employee_id) + 1 from employee;` would work better if the first ID is large.  Although you generally shouldn't worry about gaps in sequences IDs.  If you think about the way data may be inserted, updated, and then rolled back, you'll understand there's no way to have a gapless sequences without a huge performance penalty.